# Ruby on Rails Ajax rubberband

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want my users to be able to do a rubberband selection in a image for a Ruby on Rails application. Has anyone seen any good plugins that do this or make it easy for me to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around with an [image cropper](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/) that has that feature, and it uses [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), so it should be good to go for ROR. The code is pretty easy to figure out if you just want the elastic band element.

If you want to roll-your-own it's not too hard to glue a [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) Draggable object to a DIV and resize/move the DIV. See my crappy [demo](http://jameslab.moveable.com/ajaxio).